# Class instance name

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine

I have written a `RadioButton` class that contains the following `UnityEvent`:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class RadioEvent : UnityEvent<string> { }
    [Space]
    public RadioEvent OnRadioClicked = new RadioEvent();
```

I attach the script to radio button prefabs...

In the same script, I have also written a property (to find out which prefab instance was clicked on) as well as the event trigger:

```
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

        if (isRadioToggle)
            OnRadioClicked.Invoke(_name);
```

When a button is clicked, I would like to find out which one it was (its name?) so in another script that manages the radio buttons (like a container that has the buttons as children) I handle the clicking event as follows:

```
    // Subscribe to the RadioTapHandler method.
    private void Start()
    {
        _toggleButton.OnRadioClicked.AddListener(RadioTapHandler);
    }

    // Unsubscribe from the RadioTapHandler method.
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        _toggleButton.OnRadioClicked.RemoveListener(RadioTapHandler);
    }

    // What should happen when a radio toggle button is clicked?
    private void RadioTapHandler(string clickedRadioButton)
    {
        Debug.Log("The clicked radio button is: " + clickedRadioButton);
    }
```

The first strange thing is that the debug message only prints when i click on the first radio button, and not on any other button. Also, the printed debug message does not actually contain the instance name:

```
The clicked radio button is: UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
```

What am I doing wrong? Do the created instances of `RadioButton` class not get named when instantiated? Do I have t modify my `Name` property in some way to get the name of the created instances? What am I missing?

Comment: Try setting Name as gameObject.name before invoking event

Comment: Thank you. I replaced the auto setter with `set { _name = gameObject.name; }` but upon clicking, it would still log: `The clicked radio button is: UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)`

Comment: Please let it be like before, Just add this statement in Start or Awake in your script:


`Name = gameObject.name;`

Comment: @jagadheeswarreddy Many thanks. That resolved it!  I will happily mark it as Answer if you place your comment in answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this statement in Start or Awake in your script:

```
Name = gameObject.name;
```